# Testing Firebase Functions gives error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I am using Mocha to test my Functions. They work both when deployed on Firebase as well as running them locally with the emulator.

My issue is that I keep getting this error pointing to the function itself:

```
function:getTags:error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/cirrcl/crcle_backend/functions/categories/tags/getTags.js:24:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:76616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/cirrcl/crcle_backend/functions/categories/tags/getTags.js:28:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:76616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:76616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And am then I getting this error pointing to my test:

```
test:getTags:error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/cirrcl/crcle_backend/functions/test/index.test.js:17:11)
```

Here is my function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Tag = require('../../models/tag')

const uri = 'MongoDB URL'

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        const result = await Tag.find({})
        res.send({ message: 'Request fulfilled', success: true, result: result })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('function:getTags:error: ', err)
        res.send({ message: 'Unable to fulfill the request', success: false, error: err })
    }
})
```

Lastly, here is my test code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const serviceAccount = require('../../../../../keys/cirrcl-firebase.json');
const getTags = require('../categories/tags/getTags')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "DB URL"
  });

describe('Describe something here', () => {
    it('Should succeed or fail', async () => {
        try {
            const result = await getTags()
            console.log('getTags test result: ', result)
            result.should.have.status(200)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('test:getTags:error: ', err)
            // err.should.throw()
        }
    })
})
```

The only thing I can think of a credential issue, but that doesn't fully make sense since I have a cert being used (I've also tried without it as well as an app engine cert which some of the docs say to do), also since I can run this locally which is what I thought mocha was doing anyway I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

The first error is due to calling `getTags` without parameters. I have reproduced this in node like this:

test.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.send()
})
```

test2.js:

```
const test = require("./test.js");
const result = test();
console.log(result);
```

Than when you run: `node test2.js` you will get the same error.

As resolution I found example of simillar test [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-http) . This is Google Cloud Function reference which is the same as Firebase. And I have used the same approach and have created request and response parameters. After changes test2.js looked like this:

```
const test = require("./test.js");
const req = { body: {  name: 'name' }  };
const res = {send: () => console.log("test2")};
test(req, res);
```

Now if you run: `node test2.js` again you will not get any errors. So I suppose you should add the parameters to your `getTags` calling.

When it comes to 2nd error. Function `onRequest` is not returning any value so you `result` variable will always be `undefined`. As you can see running my example it will use function res.send which is sending response. I do not know mocha well enough to help you with testing, but please check the reference I passed above for similar test.

I hope this will help you figure it out...